Backpack questions: any viable way?
Backpack questions come up occasionally. We dutifully close them because such questions are story based and hard to come to consensus. This is good.
An example: You are going on a 2-week backpacking trip in the early Jurassic period. What are you taking with you?
Ok. I agree with all the VTC currently. What I want us to discuss is whether there’s a path to making such questions viable by careful phrasing and response policy (similar to Hard Science policy).
Here’s my argument: if I’m going backpacking in any real-world place, my pack is likely different from everyone else’s — it’s my personal gear. But if I ask, “What should I consider bringing?” then there’s going to be a checklist of recommended gear from previous backpackers and rangers for just about every location. And those lists vary by specific location, so they are informed answers. For those recommended items, there is a best answer, a correct answer, based on a generic person going into that area. There’s less argument about what goes into a specific backpack because an item worth arguing about for a specific backpack clearly goes on the consider list for a generic backpack.
Given that, I wonder if we can say that for a specific location/time for a generic person, is there a best recommendation list for stuff to carry?
What if such questions were answerable with a community answer such that items could be easily added/removed?
It seems a shame to me that something that has a specific answer in real world cannot get an equivalent answer here about imagined worlds. So I wonder if there’s a way.

Ask n hikers what gear to bring expect to get a minimum of n+1 contradictory answers.

I'm going to work under the assumption that a downvote shall mean "no viable way".

Adding to the answers: the problem is that questions like this are entirely circumstantial. Worldbuilding is not circumstantial. Storybuilding is. Per the [help/on-topic] we don't help people write stories. The only way around this is to provide 100% of the circumstantial details leaving only worldbuilding considerations. E.G., specifically which fauna will be encountered? Don't want to define that? Too Story-Based. The rule you need to follow is this: if you can't explain how you'll choose the accepted answer, your question is off-topic.

Be Prepared: VTC

Two Problems --- There are two basic problems with this kind of question. On the one hand, this kind of question is easily answerable. It doesn't ask for an infinite list of things and it isn't really (much of) a brainstorming session. Thus the answer falls within a relatively narrow scope. The other problem is that this question is simply not about worldbuilding in any meaningful way. There is an elaborate set-up about time machines and Jurrasic era; but the question itself boils down to "what should I take on a wilderness hike?"

Potential Solution --- So, I agree with you. Backpack questions are generally answerable by stating "The Boy Scout Handbook is a reliable source of information on what to put in a backback and here is a general list of things you should consider taking..." You are also 100% correct in noting that the list will be modified somewhat by locale, season, etc. You also point out that the specific list amounts to your own kit (making for a story based / character choice answer), so somewhere between your specific list and the general Boy Scout list there is at least one to a small and reasonable number of lists that we could generate to answer the question.

Only Real Solution --- However, therein lies the seed of the real problem. We're considering making a solid answer for a question that should not be answered in the first place. It is simply not a worldbuilding question. Getting down to the brass tax, our list of what should be considered to take into the a Jurassic setting is going to be identical to our list of what is to be considered to take into Yellowstone. In this specific case, the query itself confines us to "no futuristic or publicly unavailable technology ... stick to what you could find at the local outdoors store".

This kind of question is simply a case of not all questions are a good fit for this forum. The only real solution, therefore, is to VTC. Legitimate closure reasons include being story based / character choice; not about worldbuilding; narrative necessity. An outlier, in my opinion, would be closing the question for being opinion based.

That’s a solid analysis.


The question did not specify a duration. What I put in a little backpack for a day trip on a popular track in touristy mountains is different from what I would take for a multiple days on a tour on a much less popular area.

The question does not even specify if they are going on their trip in summer or in winter, in the mountains or on a flat plain, in a well-watered area or in a thirsty desert. Needless to say, what goes in the backpack is heavily influenced by such factors.

The question did not specify whether this is an exploration trip or a tourist trip. Do they already have good maps and weather forecasts and knowledge of any wild animals, or are they the first explorers to go and reconnoiter the area? The items to be carried are very different in the two scenarios.

The question has includes restrictions which only make sense if the trip is to be undertaken as a group of tourists, but does not include any information about what has already been done to facilitate tourist hikes.
To explain, if the travellers are the first first explorers, then I would expect them to carry aerial surveillance devices, that is, drones, collect as much video and lidar data as they can in a few hours, then return home. After making a nice map of the areas in their cosy cubicles, they would return with equipment to make a predator-proof camp. Multiple trips would be necessary, but eventually they would have a defensible camp. Then explorers with their drones and laptops could move in the camp and continue exploring, until a county-sized area had been mapped. Then the base camp would be expanded, and dangerous predators eliminated from the area. And only afterwards would carefree rich tourists be allowed to go roaming through the managed landscape.

Eight people going on a multiple-day exploration expedition through completely unknown terrain with only what they can carry in their backpacks might be the theme of an interesting story, but the author should realize that they are totally making it up out of thin air. It is pure fantasy, and I don't see how anybody could come up with a credible list of items to be carried.
The sad truth is that we know very little about Early Cretaceous conditions in any given point on Earth, even leaving aside the obvious observation that the fracking Early Cretaceous spans 20 fracking million years. (To illustrate how conditions can vary during such a timespan, 20 million years ago Antarctica still had forests, at least in some places, and most of continent was still ice-free.)
We do not know the exact geography of any place on Earth at any point during the Early Cretaceous. We have only a vague and probably completely wrong idea about what animals and plants lived during that period. We have a very very fuzzy idea about what seasons were like, about how much rain there was, about what fish and animals were good to eat and which were not and so on. It's a completely unknown world. We don't even know for sure that a human could breathe the air: maybe there were plants with poisonous pollen, who knows?


All in all, the first author's task is to create the fantasy world of the Early Cretaceous where the travellers are to go, and only afterwards decide what they will be taking with them. Are they going in the mountains, or are they going on the plains? Near a river, or in a desert? In summer or in winter? In a luxuriant forest, or in a more open landscape? And if in a more open landscape, what did it look like? (Remember there were no grasses in the Early Cretaceous. Grasses are latecomers among plant families.) Are there mosquitoes the size of small cats? Is the undergrowth alive with multicolored lizards?

Additionally personal preferences have a major impact on what individuals choose to pack even amongst a cohort who are all intending to do the same activity, for the same length of time, in the same season and location. As an example pack weight of Appalachian Trail through hikers varies wildly. In general there's a tradeoff between weight and comfort with cost being an additional factor. In the extremes of ultralight hiking people may choose to forgo some gear entirely. Questions should be worded so that a characters preferences will not impact answers.

@sphennings that’s my whole point — rewording as recommendations/considerations sidesteps the personalization.

Alex, is there any way you can imagine to make these questions answerable within WB scope? You gave a list of reasons the current question doesn’t work. I’m asking for proposals for how this kind of query could be reworded to be viable. Your answer seems to  say flatly there’s no hope. Is that your conclusion?

@SRM If you start fixing personal preferences you are asking about what a specific character will do. You could try to go the other way but good luck finding anything useful for your specific worldbuilding problem. Asking how to make a question fit WB often misses the point, making the question fit is only useful if it will still help resolve the posters problem. If they are looking for something not suitable, like wanting us to brainstorm, rewording the question will not work. There is no magic format that will garuntee that a question will remain open.

With respect to backpacks the more a question is about facts of the world and not what specific characters or organizations will do the better. Asking a question about the issued gear of an soldier is going to be easier to write than asking what do tourists bring with them. However I suspect that just making something up will probably meet your actual WB needs. Better would be ask something like "Is X type of gear likely to be doctrinally issued to an individual soldier or at a higher level of the org chart?" or whatever the actual sticking point is.

@sphennings My goal is to make our site as helpful as possible. I'm looking at the kind of information being requested and comparing to what is probably needed for writing a story. When i do that evaluation, I can see an answer that seems to me to be both finitely answerable (albeit long) and useful to a storyteller. I'm trying to see if there's a path forward. There may not be. It may be that such questions are permanently beyond our domain. That's fine, but I felt it was worth investigating.

There is a whole range of worldbuilding questions that are not appropriate for this site. This restrictive philosophy is at the core of Stack Exchange's whole design. The goal isn't to answer questions. The goal is to be a repository of high quality answers that are useful to others too. That's why broad and POB questions are prohibited. It's not about the domain. Every topic could be relevant to building some world. It's that the the type of question is not permitted here. Writing a good question is difficult but requiring that makes it easy to write high quality answers.

Importantly rarely is the issue with a question something where using different words will be sufficient to address it. The issues tend to be in what is being asked of us not the specific words used.

Instead of your backpack question, instead ask "what modern camping equipment would be ideal to have for time-traveling hikers going to the Jurassic Period?" That question should be legal and viable here; that said list-based questions in general aren't popular so your mileage may vary.

That's still lacking sufficient context to be useful. Where are they hiking, how long, what is the purpose of the hike, etc... What I consider ideal to bring on a hike will change quite a bit just when hiking in my home state. Factor in all the unknowns and the question has far to many equally valid answers to be appropriate for this site. If you can't get Appalachian Trail through hikers to agree on what the ideal gear is how exactly do you expect a much less specific question to not have many valid answers?

@sphennings those details go in the question body. There is a character limit for the question title.

Similar to how Stack Oveflow requires you to provide the minimum reproduceable example, instead of just dumping all your code and error message, we expect people to ask the most narrow form that is still useful. Don't ask what to bring on a Jurassic hike if you actually want to ask about specifically a 100 mile unsupported hike through the jungle. We also don't judge questions by their topic per. se. as long as they're about worldbuilding they're OK. We do judge based on how the question is asked. Is the question too broad? Too based in opinion? That's a problem regardless of topic.
